# How can I return a String in floating point format two decimal places to the right?

Tags: java, string, junit, decimal, decimalformat

Currently my toString method displays integer balances with a single digit
after the decimal point. It displays this way in the JUnit test: "expected <20.0> but was: <200.0>" I need <200.00> instead of <200.0>. I've tried several different formulas but can't seem to get it. Thanks!

```
  public class Bank {

    private String name;
    private double balance;
    private String acctNum;

    public Bank(String a, String n, double b) {
        name = n;
        acctNum = a;
        balance = b;
    }

    public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        // new DecimalFormat("###.##").format(getBalance());
        return "Account Number: " + getAcctnum() + "Name: " + getName() + "Balance: "
                + (f.format(getBalance()));
    }

    // JUnit test case:
    @Test
    public void testToString() {
        Bank b = new Bank("341ngr", "Joe Smoe", 200);
        assertEquals("Joe Smoe", b.getName());
        assertEquals("341ngr", b.getAcctnum());
        assertEquals(20, b.getBalance(), 0.001);
    }
}
```

Comment: try String.format("%.2f",getBalance())

Comment: Gave it a try `return "Account Num: " + getAccountnum() + "Name: " + 
    getCustomerName() + "Balance: " + String.format("%.2f",getBalance());` and nothing changed but thanks!

Comment: in your assertEqual lines, try this: assertEquals("20.0",String.format("%.2f", b.getBalance()))

Comment: Thank you so much! This ended up working: `assertEquals(200.0, String.format("%.2f", b.getBalance()));` I wish i could give you an up vote! @Pooya

Comment: I put it in the answers so the question can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your assertEqual lines, try this:

```
assertEquals("20.0",String.format("%.2f", b.getBalance()));
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use

```
String.format( "%.2f", yourdoublevalue);
```